# Thinking of the group $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ as a single-object category?

Tags: category-theory

I am totally new to the category theory and my question might sound stupid. Nevertheless, I am eager to understand.

I assume existence of category $C$ with a single object $A$. So each an every arrow in this category deliberately points back to itself. In other words, all the maps there are $A \mapsto A$.

Now, at this point, nothing guarantees that those $A \mapsto A$ morphism are indeed **isomorphisms**. It appears to happen only when any group emerges, since, by definition, whatever group required to ship pairs of $(a, a^{-1})$; hence, it is perfectly fine to acknowledge the existence of $a \mapsto a^{-1}$ morphism together with $a^{-1} \mapsto a$, which both make $(a, a^{-1})$ isomorphic to each other.

Next step is to define, let say, $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ group as a category $C$. At this point I fail:

> Then category $C$ consists of set (or class) $A \mapsto A$ maps and associative composition function $(A, A) \times (A, A) \mapsto (A, A)$.

I can't understand: $(+)$ is not an instance of $(A, A) \times (A, A) \mapsto (A, A)$. So somehow $(+) : (g \in A, g' \in A) \mapsto g'' \in A$ must be "upgraded" to become an $((+, +), (+, +)) \mapsto (+, +)$ and I see no clear yet obvious way to achieve it.

So my question is: what is the magic trick to get the Cartesian product of **binary operators** given by any group such that it satisfy above-mentioned requirement? It would be really great if you stick to the $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ example.

Comment: One-object categories are essentially monoids.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, but monoid required to provide a binary operation on it's elements, not the binary compositor of maps. So the question is still there - how to jump from having a binary operator on the elements of an underlying set to the "associative compostion function" from the quote in my OP, which folds MAPS, NOT ELEMENTS OF THE SET.

Comment: An arrow doesn't "point back to itself," you have an arrow from a single object to itself. Call this object $A$. If $(A,A)$ is meant to represent the set of morphisms from $A$ to $A$, then I presume we're talking about $(A,A)=\Bbb Z$, and of course there's a binary operation $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z$, addition.

Comment: @SerejaBobolubov NO NEED TO SHOUT! With a one-element category, you have a set of morphisms, a composition law, which composes a pair of morphisms, and an identity morphism. Moreover, composition is required to be associative. All of this is just the data for a monoid.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, still can't get you. Say, I got $1 + 1 = 2$. That's clearly a binary operation on the $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$. But it does not compose **morphisms** (i.e. maps), it composes **elements of the underlying set**. How to fill gap between composition of **morphisms** having only composition of **elements** of the underlying set?

Comment: @SerejaBobolubov The numbers **are** the morphisms. Nobody said morphisms in a category must be set-theoretic maps. So, yes, addition does compose morphisms - i.e. it is an associative binary operation on the set of morphisms, and there is an identity morphism (namely the number $0$).

Comment: @anon, so looks like I totally misunderstand the concept of "morphism". What is it then, if not a map from something to something?

Comment: @SerejaBobolubov In category theory the morphisms are just things satisfying the category axioms.

Comment: Anything, really. For example, if $P$ is a partially ordered set, then we can view ordered pairs $(p,q)$ with $p\le q$ as morphisms $p\to q$. All that's really required is that there are operations between these sets of morphisms mimicking composition of functions. If you want a more concrete description of $\Bbb Z$ as a one-object category, where the morphisms *are* set-theoretic functions, interpret $\Bbb Z$ as an object and a map $f_n(x):=x+n$ as a morphism. Then composition is $f_m\circ f_n=f_{m+n}$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown so, morphism could be literally anything? I guess, there should be at least 2 endpoints of the morphism, i.e. morphism can happen only between distinct things like $A$ and $B$ regardless of what exactly they are?

Comment: @SerejaBobolubov That is part of the category axioms; a morphism has a domain and a codomain, which are objects of the category.

Comment: @SerejaBobolubov The domain and codomain do *not* need to be distinct ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me explain how a one-element category can be viewed as a monoid, since I think this already gets to the source of the confusion: that *elements of the structure* correspond to *morphisms* in one-element category, not "elements" of the unique object.

So suppose I have a one-element category $C$ with unique object $x$. There is a natural monoid $M_C$ associated to this category:

- Elements of $M_C$ are morphisms in $C$ - that is, the underlying set of $M_C$ is $Hom_C(x, x)$.
- The monoid operation $*$ in $M_C$ is given by composition: for $f, g\in Hom_c(x, x)$ we define $f*g=fg$.

Note that the *elements of the monoid* are the *morphisms of $C$*, not the *elements of $x$* in any sense (indeed we don't need to think of $x$ as a thing that even *has* elements).

The structure of $M_C$ now comes from how $Hom_C(x, x)$ behaves.

---

OK, now I claim that *every* monoid arises in this way: that is, for a given monoid $A$, there is a category $C_A$ with a single object $x$ such that $M_{C_A}\cong M$.

It doesn't matter what our unique object is - let's take $x$ to be the number $37$. Now the hom-set $Hom_C(x, x)$ will be the set of elements of $A$, and the composition law will be given by $fg=f*g$ where $*$ is the monoid operation in $A$.

This feels totally artificial, and it is - but that's fine! A category is *any structure* satisfying [list of properties], and it's easy to check that the above structure does in fact satisfy those properties. In particular, the identity element $e_A$ of the monoid is the identity morphism $id_x$.

Comment: By saying "elements of the monoid are the morphisms of $C$", do you mean that there are "arrows" in-between all possible pairs $S \times S$, where $S$ denote underlying set of the monoid?

Comment: @SerejaBobolubov No, I mean literally that the elements of the monoid are the morphisms of $C$. And the monoid operation is composition (in the sense of the category).

Comment: If you want to write it this way, you can define it as "$*: Hom_C(x, x)\times Hom_C(x, x)\rightarrow Hom_C(x, x): (f, g)\mapsto f\circ g$," but that's just a really longwinded way of saying what I said above.

Comment: As far as I understand now, "morphism" is an arrow pointing from one element of the underlying set to somewhay another or even itself?

Comment: @SerejaBobolubov A morphism is an arrow pointing from one element of the set of objects ("underlying set" seems a bit weird in this context) **of the category** to another (or possibly the same) element of the set of objects **of the category**. But the set of objects of the category is **not** the underlying set of the monoid: the underlying set of the monoid is, once again, the set of morphisms in the category.

Comment: Maybe a better way to phrase this: given any category at all, the set of morphisms - ignoring the objects entirely - forms a set with a partial binary operation, namely composition. It's partial since not all pairs of morphisms can be composed. If, however, the category has only one object, then composition is total (since all morphisms have the same source and target, namely that unique object). So in a one-object category, the set of morphisms comes equipped with a total binary operation, composition. From the category axioms we know that this composition is associative and has an identity.

Comment: But that's exactly what a monoid is - a set of things, together with a binary operation which is associative and has an identity! Note that this completely ignores the actual "nature" of the unique object, or indeed of the morphisms themselves; it only pays attention to *how the morphisms interact with each other* on an abstract level. (This is an important theme of category theory.)

Comment: It is already like 3rd time I am re-reding your answer. Let me try to make intermediate conclusions. 1) Morphism is **always** an arrow from the object belonging to a category to yet another object of that particular category (in extreme case, it might point to itself - an that's exactly what happens here: we got no more that a single object, and all the morphisms-arrows are "circular"). 2) Morphism might represent literally **any** logical statement about two objects: whenever it holds true to a given particular pair, arrow exists.

Comment: 3) As such, morphisms are "ordered": having an arrow from $A$ to $B$ does not imply in general the reverse arrow from $B$ to $A$ (as long as it takes place, there is an **iso**morphism between $A$ and $B$, no?). 4) Finally, any category is nothing but a directed graph, where verticies represent objects and connections between those are morphisms?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72679/discussion-between-sereja-bobolubov-and-noah-schweber).